# Python - Pandas "BadGzipFile" Error When Reading in ".json.gz" File

Tags: python, json, pandas, gzip

I am trying to read in data from a ".json.gz" file as a dataframe. I keep getting an error indicating that it is a "BadGzipFile". However, when I unzip the file manually (i.e., just double clicking it in my finder), I am able to successfully open the json file. This leads me to believe that the file is fine, but when I run the below code in Python, I receive the "BadGzipFile" error.

I am very new to .gzip files and have done a fair bit of research trying to figure out what the issue is. So far, I have been unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
import os
import json
import gzip

file_path = '/data/data_0_0_0.json.gz'

with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_json(f, compression='gzip', lines=True)
```

And here is the error I am receiving:

```
BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'{"')
```

Comment: Did you test unpacking the file with another program except python to make sure the file is ok? Are you sure the path should be an absolute path with / in the beginning or should it be a relative path instead?

Comment: So, I have opened the file manually (just by double clicking it in my finder) and I can get it to open successfully. I am fairly confident it should work with an absolute path-- I can look into this some more, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening with your code here:

```
with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_json(f, compression='gzip', lines=True)
```

Is that you're opening a Gzip file at `file_path`. Then you're telling Pandas that the thing that you opened (`f`), is itself another Gzip file. It isn't; it's a Json file. When it says `BadGzipFile` with that starting bracket, it is telling you that the file it found starts with a bracket instead of the [Gzip file's magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#:%7E:text=%22gzip%22%20is%20often%20also%20used,and%20the%20operating%20system%20ID.).

---

You should change it either to open the file with `gzip` and then directly read the resulting file or have Pandas read the file.

The first would be:

```
with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True)
```

The second is actually easier. Because `pd.read_json` will [infer the compression](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) format based on the file name and your file ends with `.gz`, you can just write:

```
df = pd.read_json(file_path)
```